# Відредагувати контент після того, як сторінка Kyiv на Wikipedia нарешті отримала нормальну назву

Tags: discussion, editing

### Спочатку хороша новина

Після 15 років [дискусій](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Kyiv) і [більше десятка спроб](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Kyiv/naming) перейменувати сторінку, попри шалений опір ворожих інтернет-тролів (в тому числі таких, які мають велику репутацію як редактори Вікіпедії; високопрофесійних і тому високооплачуваних), сторінка англійської Вікіпедії [Kyiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyiv) стала основною, а [Kiev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev) стала сторінкою перенаправлення.

Не можу утриматися, щоб привітати українську спільноту з, без перебільшення, величезною перемогою на ниві інформаційного захисту незалежності України. Від себе скажу, що я навіть боюся уявити бюджет московської кібертерористичної банди «Ольгіно», який був виділений **лише** на спроби запобігти перейменуванню сторінки на Wikipedia. Якщо здоровий глузд людства переважив силу численних московських тролів, значить, не все ще втрачено! :)

#### Власне, запитання

Нам варто пройтися по всіх дописах на цьому сайті (SE пошук: `url:"kiev"`) і змінити посилання, а також роздуми і аргументи щодо перейменування. Я знайшов і відредагую наступні сторінки:

- https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/300/

Comment: Дякую. Вас теж вітаю. Додам від себе в сам пост ще посилання, якщо знайду.

Comment: Не зовсім зрозумів, що саме Ви пропонуєте шукати. Якщо я Вас правильно зрозумів: [url:"kiev"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=url=%22kiev%22) знаходить сторінки, де згадуються _веб-адреси_ з відповідним словом, — але `kiev.ua` і `kyiv.ua` — це _різні_ домени, у більшості випадків не буде можливості підставити один замість іншого. Чи я Вас неправильно зрозумів?

Comment: @Sasha, насправді, треба шукати сторінки лише з домену Вікіпедії `wikipedia.org/*/kiev` або такі, що відповідають масці `*wiki/kiev`. А ті, що `kiev.ua`, — пропустити. Але мені не вдалося зробити пошук, який не довелося б далі фільтрувати.